# Duvida quanto a configuração de docker-compose e Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Subi um pequeno ambiente de desenvolvimento. São 2 containers:

- mysql (mysql:5.7)
- web (php:7.1-apache)

Minha dúvida está em um parâmetro de configuração do docker-compose.yml e Dockerfile, respectivamente:

- ports
- EXPOSE

Qual a diferença de ambos?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SENHA_AQUI
      MYSQL_DATABASE: webapp
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: senha_aqui
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: web_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./htdocs/:/var/www
      - ./apache/:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Resolvi sub

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

MAINTAINER Fabio J L Ferreira <fabiojaniolima@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl unzip git npm && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin/ --filename=composer

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como citou a diferença começa no "escopo", onde cada um é aplicado. `EXPOSE` está no escopo de imagem, no `Dockerfile` enquanto `port` na criação de *container*, seja no *compose file* atraveś do [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports), [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) com os parâmetros `-p`/`--publish=[]`/`--service-ports` ou sem *compose* usando [`docker create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) ou [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) e os parâmetro `-p`/`--publish`/`-P`/`--publish-all`.

Então, apesar das diferentes formas, temos conceitualmente a diferença na imagem e nos *containers*. Na criação da imagem [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) significa que o(s) serviço(s) no *container* "escutam" em determinada(s) porta(s, independente se a porta em questão será publicada ou não, além de servir como instrução a quem usará a imagem, informando quais portas podem ser publicadas de forma segura.

Como exemplo, se tenho no `Dockerfile` para criação de uma imagem *XPTO* algo como `EXPOSE 80` significa que, independente da forma da criação de *container* de *XPTO*, esta porta poderá estar acessível entre outros *containers* da mesma rede.

Em resumo, quanto a exposição/publicação de portas:

- sem usar `EXPOSE` e nem `-p` (ou outras variações comentadas): a(s) porta(s) do serviço rodando não estarão acessível de lugar nenhum, a não ser dentro do próprio *container*;
- usando `EXPOSE` e `-p` (ou outras variações comentadas): a(s) porta(s) especificada(s) no `Dockerfile` estará(ão) acessível(is) tanto ENTRE *containers* *E* através do *host*;
- usando apenas `EXPOSE`: a(s) porta(s) especificada(s) no `Dockerfile` estará(ão) acessível(is) apenas ENTRE *containers* na mesma rede, mas não através do *host*

Além disso, se você usar `-p`, mas não usou `EXPOSE`, o docker implicitamente irá fazer um `EXPOSE`. Isto porque se você está abrindo a porta publicamente então ela pode ser acessível entre os *containers* também.

Por último há ainda o [`expose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) no escopo de *compose* que neste caso significa que a porta estará disponível apeans para os *services* da *compose*, mas não são publicadas para a máquina *host*.

Comment: Compreendi, no meu caso como estou usando ports no docker-compose.yml caio neste cenário: Além disso, se você usar -p, mas não usou EXPOSE, o docker implicitamente irá fazer um EXPOSE. Isto porque se você está abrindo a porta publicamente então ela pode ser acessível entre os containers também. Certo?

Comment: Exato, verificando o status você observa bem o comportamento. Como boa prática eu gosto de usar o `EXPOSE`, principalmente quando a imagem será distribuída, fica claro para o usuário o que é exposto

Comment: Quando você fala que fica claro, está se referindo que ao inspecionar a imagem, mesmo sem o Dockerfile é possível ver as portas expostas? Além disso, se usar EXPOSE, não preciso da referência (porta) no docker-compose.yml?

Comment: 1. não entendi essa pergunta; 2. isso, não precisa, entre os containers na mesma rede as portas são acessíveis - padrão quando _compose_, mas não o serão através da máquina _host_.

Comment: Compreendi. Para encerrar este post tenho uma ultima dúvida, ao adicionar o EXPOSE ao Dockerfile estou gerando uma nova layer?

Comment: Sim, toda instrução do docker ao construir uma imagem gera uma _layer_. Use `docker history <sua_imagem>` veja todas as _layers_  das suas imagens.

Answer (score 0):

No Docker cada container por padrão possui uma interface de rede, virtual e própria. Isso significa que cada container ganha um IP interno.

O EXPOSE é um metadado que explica, para consumidores, que sua aplicação ou serviço expõem porta(s). Note, ele explica, mas não faz nada. A única função prática é permitir que no subcomando DOCKER RUN/CREATE você possa usar o parâmetro -P para fazer BIND de PORTAS dinamicamente, de acordo com as portas livres no seu host.

Todo container, por padrão, tem todas as suas portas liberadas o que significa que no IP do Container, portas que você definiu no EXPOSE ou não, podem ser acessadas. Containers em uma mesma rede bridge conseguem acessar outros containers e se comunicar com qualquer porta destes, independente da existência prévia de uma definição de EXPOSE.

PORTS, é a configuração do Docker-Compose referente ao BIND de PORTAS, que faz com que uma ponte entre o host e o container seja feita, para portas especificadas.

Para finalizar, sendo pragmático: EXPOSE não serve pra nada, exceto informar que portas seu container usará. Nenhum processo ou mecanismo valida ou se baseia nisso para fazer nada, exceto o caso do -P, como disse no parágrafo anterior.
Mas é uma boa prática, e não deve ser ignorado na hora de criar imagens. É importante deixar claro quais portas serão usadas, isso facilita, e muitas vezes ajuda a entender alguns problemas de acoplamento, por exemplo.