# Como expor mais de uma porta de um container Docker?

Tags: docker

Eu tenho um container docker que possui redis e xdebug instalado.

Um cliente do Redis instalado no host precisa acessar esse serviço através da porta 6379 e no host o intellij precisa acessar a porta 9000 para fazer a debogagem com o xdebug.

A minha pergunta é qual a maneira correta de expor essas portas, além da 80?

Seria no Dockerfile? Essa opção é obrigatória se quisermos expor as portas?

```
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 9000
```

Ou seria quando carregar a imagem? Se essa opção for usada a opção anterior seria necessária?

```
-p 80:80
-p 6379:6379
-p 9000:9000
```

Comment: Você está tratando container como VM, e isso um erro. Seja lá quem responda pela porta 80, não deveria estar no mesmo container em que o redis está. Esse container muito provavelmente deveria ser desmembrado em 3 containers, orquestrados em um docker-compose. Você no mínimo reaproveita uma imagem (redis), caso não reaproveite as demais.

Comment: Quanto ao redis eu concordo com vc. Deveríamos usar 2 containers - 1 para cada serviço. Mas foi uma decisão da empresa manter o REDIS no mesmo container. O que eu não entendo é quanto ao terceiro container q vc mencionou. Vc quer dizer é que eu deveria usar um container para o xdebug?

Comment: Por não conhecer o xdebug eu não fui tão enfático em dizer que com toda certeza são 3. Agora que vi o que é, esse deveria estar junto do PHP sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, dê uma olhada [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244047#244047) que fala um pouco mais sobre as diferenças de publicação/exposição de portas.

> Seria no Dockerfile? Essa opção é obrigatória se quisermos expor as portas?

Usar o [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) na definição das imagens, neste caso, pode não ser necessário, mas é sempre boa prática, já que funciona como um tipo de documentação. Ao usar `EXPOSE` você diz ao usuário da imagem quais portas e em qual protocolo poderão ser expostas ao host - ou em outras *networks* - de forma segura. Como dito, não é obrigatório seu uso.

> Ou seria quando carregar a imagem? Se essa opção for usada a opção anterior seria necessária?

Ao usar a publicação/exposição na criação e/ou execução de containers não será necessário o `EXPOSE` explícito. Ao usar a publicação de portas ao *host* na criação de container ou execução de container já existente, caso você não tenha explicitado com o `EXPOSE` quais portas intencionalmente podem e/ou devem ser expostas, o docker implicitamente irá fazer o `EXPOSE` - ele não altera a imagem, no entanto.

> A minha pergunta é: qual a maneira correta de expor essas portas, além da 80?

Em resumo, não há uma maneira "correta", você pode combinar as maneiras ou usá-las separadamente, vai depender de como os containers irão rodar - quanto a *networks*, principalmente -, de como estruturou seus containers, etc.

No seu caso, no entanto, você precisa que determinadas portas estejam acessível no *host*, que é onde seu IDE está rodando. Neste caso recomenda-se que seja usado tanto `EXPOSE`, tanto pelo seu uso como documentação quanto dará maior flexibilidade a um usuário terceiro de sua imagem, além de ser necessário que as portas sejam publicadas para acesso pelo *host*, então você precisará do `-p/`--publish`/`-P/`--publish-all`. Mesmo assim você pode não precisar publicar todas ao *host*, caso não seja mandatório que *host* tenha acesso a todas as portas citadas - como, por exemplo, a *6379* ser acessada apenas por outro container na mesma rede.

P.S.: no seu *dockerfile* você pode informar as portas em apenas uma única instrução, como `EXPOSE 80 6379 9000`. Isto irá criar um único *layer*, facilita a inspenção de imagens na maior parte dos casos.